# silverlight for embedded systems

Tags: silverlight

Hi 
I am developing silverlight application using Blend2 and VS2008 for Embedded systems and I installed all the requirements.
Now i need to develop my silverlight application using C++
But in blend2 when i start silverlight application its showing only C# and VB only
Previously i did one sample application in blend2 and i gave control for that buttons using C# in VS2008
now i want make it control using C++ 
Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight = C# or VB only. No C++.

Comment: This is not true. Silverlight for Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3 and Windows Embedded Compact 7 is based on C++.

Comment: Really? I've had no idea, any links please?

Comment: Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502198.aspx it says "Silverlight for Windows Embedded is a native (C++) UI development framework for Windows Embedded Compact devices (...)"